# What am I doing wrong here? involving inequality

Tags: inequality

It may be very stupid question, please bear with me.

Recall we define $|a|=a$ if $a\geq 0$ and $|a|=-a $ if $a\leq 0$

Now we have, 
$$-a\leq |a|\leq a$$
and $$-b\leq|b|\leq b$$

so using these two I get $$-(a+b)\leq |a|+b|\leq  a+b$$

That imply $$||a|+|b||\leq |a+b|$$

But this is incorrect as take $a=1,b=-1$, we get $LHS=2$, but $RHS=0$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: *Hint:* $-b\leq|b|\leq b$ is already wrong for $b=-1$.

Comment: Thanks. I am feeling stupid now :(

Comment: You want to prove $$||a|+|b||\geq |a+b|$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
-a\leq |a|\leq a
$$
does *not* hold in general, it is wrong for negative numbers. What you probably meant is
$$
-|a|\leq a\leq |a| \\
-|b|\leq b\leq |b| 
$$
and adding those inequalities gives
$$
-|a| -|b|\leq a+b\leq |a| + |b| 
$$
which is the well-known triangle inequality
$$
|a+b| \le |a| + |b| \,  .
$$

Comment: Thanks. Martin, for quick response.